# How to get the number of confirmations of a TX on a different network using Chainlink?

Tags: chainlink

What would be the most reliable way of checking if a given TX on different network has been confirmed k times using Chainlink?

I know I can make an API call to Etherscan, for instance, but since this is a common use-case I wonder if there are more reliable well-known methods for doing it.

Chainlink itself advertises Cross-Chain solutions (https://chain.link/solutions/cross-chain) but I could not find any technical documentation about those. Pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

[Chainlink CCIP (Cross-Chain Interoperability Protocol)](https://chain.link/solutions/cross-chain) is still in development.

In the meantime, you can make an API call to another blockchain with the [Chainlink API feature.](https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/) You'll have to do some work to make sure that you have enough nodes making the API calls to make sure it's decentralized, but that's essentially it!